# Update...Set...From...Where query is affecting all rows and not specific ones

Tags: sql-server

The below query should only affect the row titled 'F0085'. However, it has affected all the rows. Setting the address to 'test' on every Job_No.

```
UPDATE TBTest.dbo.Site 
SET Address ='FDAN' 
FROM Jobs 
WHERE Job_No = 'F0085'
```

This is the first table:

[image]

Comment: Update Syntax is `UPDATE ... join .. SET ..WHERE`

Comment: You need to correlate the rows in the 2 tables. Post the DDL for the tables involved.

Comment: Jen/Dan, Yes it is MS SQL. How do I use the Join Syntax (Would this be INNER JOIN?)  or correlate the two tables? Please excuse my ignorance, I am relatively new to SQL

Comment: @DanHanson The syntax is `UPDATE t SET ... FROM Table1 t JOIN Table2 tt ON ... WHERE ...`. With this code, you will update rows in table `Table1`.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql) you have docs and also examples (near end of site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I needed to find the common column (the ID column).

```
UPDATE t
SET 
t.Address = 'FDAN'
FROM
TBTest.dbo.Site t
INNER JOIN Jobs j
ON t.Site_ID = j.Job_ID
WHERE j.Job_No = 'F0085'
```

I don't fully understand how the aliases work. But it appears to be working fine.

Comment: I posted the same. You marked it as answer and then removed it and posted the same again. That's not how SO works mate

Comment: Please note. yours is not identical to the one I posted (see ID). I have ticked yours if you insist. however after trying this a few times. it still seems to not work correctly. It will only work with the top job number  (ID No 1), and then it alters all of the addresses to the single value I stated for the top job number.

Comment: Mate, for precise answers, you need to post table DDL and DML. Even you were unsure about common columns. :) Anyway I am not insisting on anything. If the solution doesn't work, untick it.

Comment: @Prabhat G ok thanks sorry for the misunderstanding, what is a DDL DML?

Comment: It means `create table` schema and some sample data.

Comment: @Prabhat G I do not know how to do that so ill start from the beginning and explain the best I can. I have two tables within a database(TBTest.dbo): Site & Jobs. I would like to create a Query which looks at Job_No column in Jobs and finds a stated job, lets say 'B0210' and alters the address column in Site against that job. All the tables must be linked some how because I have a query that selects columns from Site & Jobs and puts them together in a table. (I believe the common (locked) column is Job_ID & Site ID.

Comment: This is the code for creating the joint table SELECT        Company.Company_Name, Jobs.Job_No, Jobs.Job_Name, Jobs.Job_ID, Jobs.Job_Summary, Site.Address
FROM            Company INNER JOIN
 Site ON Company.Company_ID = Site.Company_ID CROSS JOIN
                         Jobs

Comment: This is the query to edit the site address against a job number. UPDATE TBTest.dbo.Site
SET TBTest.dbo.Site.Address = 'TEST4'
FROM
TBTest.dbo.Site 
JOIN Jobs 
ON TBTest.dbo.Jobs.Job_ID = TBTest.dbo.Site.Site_ID 
WHERE TBTest.dbo.Jobs.Job_No = 'B0210'

Comment: @Prabhat G When I run the above query it wont do anything unless the job name is the top name within the table. if I put the job name as the top one, it alters the addresses against all of the jobs. please advise? within the query runner it states that it has successfully affected one row, but affects them all.

Comment: If your `select` query is right, I believe this query will work : `UPDATE b
SET b.Address ='TEST4'
FROM 
Company a INNER JOIN Site b
ON a.Company_ID = b.Company_ID 
CROSS JOIN 
Jobs c
WHERE c.Job_No = 'B0210'`

Comment: @Prabhat G Thank you for your patience. This has worked to a degree. I can now select any Job number to run the query (Not just the top name). However, it alters the address to 'Test4' against all of the job numbers not the specific job number in the query ('B0210'). I feel we are very close!

Comment: This is happening because in my opinion because we have `cross join` which relates 1 job with all sites. I can help you better if you post the SELECT statement in your question and also paste its output.

Comment: @Prabhat G See comment 7 for my select statement. The table then shows columns as follows:      A number, Company_Name, Job_No, Job_Name, Job_ID, Job_Summary, Address. I could send a screen shot of this but I do not know how to upload.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. Since your update depends on other table, you need to `join` them. Try:

```
UPDATE t
SET 
t.Address = 'FDAN'
FROM
TBTest.dbo.Site t
INNER JOIN JOBS j
ON t.Job_No = j.Job_No
WHERE j.Job_No = 'F0085'
```

Comment: I have tried the following but no luck.

`UPDATE TBTest.dbo.Site` 
`SET TBTest.dbo.Site.Address = 'FDAN'`
`FROM TBTest.dbo.Site`
`INNER JOIN Jobs ON TBTest.dbo.Site.Job_No = TBTest.dbo.Jobs` 
`WHERE TBTest.dbo.Jobs.Job_No = 'F0085'`

I get the following errors:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'Job_No'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "TBTest.dbo.Jobs" could not be bound.

Comment: @DanHanson use aliases and everything will be ok (just like Prabhat wrote).

Comment: @Rokuto Thanks, I now get the following: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Invalid column name 'Job_No'. Do I need to set the aliases? also INNER JOIN is greyed out?

Comment: @DanHanson Well, I don't know structure of your tables and I don't know how to join proparly tables `Site` and `Jobs`. You need to change line `ON t.Job_No = j.Job_No` and replace `t.Job_No` with proper column.

Comment: @Dan : greyed out inner join is fine. Its how SSMS shows it. Can you tell me which is the common column between `Site` and `Jobs` ?

Comment: @Prabhat G: There is no common column apart from the ID I guess, basically I view the tables within excel. In excel I have 5 columns in total, 3 from one table, and 2 others from 2 more tables. I would like to edit the address on a particular job number. both of which are in separate tables

Comment: @Dan : lets discuss this over chat : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61598/update-table-query

Comment: @Prabhat G: I have now got the query working within SQL, However, when I convert this to VBA it states an incorrect syntax around 'J'?     ` "UPDATE t SET t.Address =" & "'" & UserForm1.TextBox4.Value & "'" & "FROM TBTest.dbo.Site t INNER JOIN Jobs j ON t.Site_ID = j.Job_ID" & "WHERE j.Job_No =" & "'" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & "';"`

Comment: @Prabhat G   I have marked it as an answer.  Stack over flow will not enable me to ask another question today. please can you help with the above

Comment: let me try please join the chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61598/update-table-query

Comment: @Prabhat G I cannot speak on the chat unless I have 20 points

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TBTest.dbo.Site  ST
INNER JOIN Jobs JB ON JB.Job_No=ST.JOB_NO
SET ST.Address =JB.Address
```

Try above query.